# printing out the opposite of a ladder in a loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I want to print out this but I am having trouble with it using while loops or for loop.

```
#######
#####
###
#
```

But my code with the while loop prints out this

```
#
##
###
####
#####
```

I don't know how to print it backwards could someone help me.

```
public class oppositeloop
{
    public void oppositelad(){

     int g = 1;
     
     char f = '#';
     
    while (g <= 5){
        int r= 1;
        while(r <= g){
            System.out.print(f);
            r += 1;
        }
        g += 1;
        System.out.println();
    }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        oppositeloop n = new oppositeloop();
        
        n.oppositelad();
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Start with `g` == 4 (or whatever) and decrement it, don't increment.  Exit when g < 0.

Comment: Just reverse the outer loop. Iterate from 5 to 1

Comment: Bisides, though not relevant to the question, 1. use capital letter for class name 2. maybe make your current method `oppositelad`  a static method. Then you don't have to initialize this class which really makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
    // How many lines to print
    for (int i = 4; i > 0; i--) {
      // How many '#' to print in that line
      for (int j = 0; j < 2 * i - 1; j++) {
         System.out.print("#");
      }
      // To next line
      System.out.print("\n");
    }
```

Comment: it doesnt work for me i enter 4 for how many lines to print then 7 to print in that line and it is a forever for loop

Comment: @boovmber Sorry there was a typo (should be `i--`), try it again now.